# JQuery ready function difference

Tags: jquery, function

Please help me understand the difference between the below code:

```
(function() {

//-----some code-----

}());
```

and:

```
(function($){

//-----some code-----

})(jQuery);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is called no-conflict mode. This means if other frameworks are using the `$` sign to mean something else other then the jQuery object, it will not conflict with it. The reason for this is because you are specifying that the `$` that you mean is the `jQuery` that you pass into the function call!

Remember, a Javascript function can be run immediately like this.

```
(function(){

})();
```

So popping in the last pair of brackets [the function call] the `jQuery` puts the `jQuery` object in the function that runs immediately.